# Angular 2 getting the Google Authentication status from a service

Tags: angular, google-api, angular2-services, google-authentication

I'm successfully signing in and out using Google authentication, but my auth service isn't returning the sign in status. I'm trying to read it in my Auth Guard to determine if I should direct to the login page. I'm getting the error that `_googleAuth` is undefined ("TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSignedIn' of undefined").

```
constructor(private router: Router, private _authService: AuthenticationService) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
            return this._authService.getAuthenticatedStatusAsObservable()
            .map((result) => { ...
```

The descriptively named service method looks like this:

```
getAuthenticatedStatusAsObservable(): Observable<boolean>  {
    if(this._googleAuth){
      return Observable.of(this._googleAuth.isSignedIn.get());
    }
    else {return Observable.of(false) }
  }
}
```

Other service methods work. I can write out the username for example. However, when I try to get the status (or the username) as an observable, it's not working.

Why isn't having the authentication service in the constructor enough? I assume I'm missing something about using observables.

loadAuth() is called in the service constructor:

```
loadAuth() {
  // attempt to SILENT authorize
  this.gapiLoad
    .load('auth2')
    .switchMap(() => this.authorize())
    .do((googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) => this.saveGoogleAuth(googleAuth))
    .do((googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) => this.listenToGoogleAuthSignIn(googleAuth))
    .filter((googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) => this.isSignedIn())
    .filter((googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) => this.hasAccessToken(googleAuth))
    .map((googleAuth: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth) => googleAuth.currentUser.get())
    .subscribe((googleUser: gapi.auth2.GoogleUser) => {
      this.zone.run(() => this.handleSuccessLogin(googleUser));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Show how did you initialize `this._googleAuth`?

Comment: @RomanC added it. thx

Comment: it's failing somewhere on the first three lines, you should debug. Sorry this is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check when your code is initializing gapi.auth2.

This is what you'll need to check the Google auth signed in status.

```
var result = false;
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    //gapi.auth2.init(authOptions); // if you haven't initialized yet
    //get instance with client ID, must be called after gapi.auth2.init
    var googleAuthTest = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    result = googleAuthTest.isSignedIn.get();
});
```

Comment: You're right. My code was initializing gapi.auth2 for the sign in but I wasn't using GetAuthInstance later. The one wrinkle for anyone reading this is you can't initialize it twice. You'll get the error "already initialized with different options."